# How can I split an xts object into chunks of similar size, but continuously not randomly?

Tags: r, split, time-series, xts

I did this but split the series into random chunks: chunks <- split(GC, f = 1:3)

I need continuous chunks, taking into account the date that is in the index.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data and your desired output? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for guidance.